# Why runs JVM on Windows 10 in headless mode? How to disable headless?

Tags: java, awt

On my **arch linux (i3wm/open jdk8)** and **windows 10 (oracle jdk8)** machines `java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()` returns instances of `sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit` which does not supports **system tray icons**.

**How can one disable this mode and enable system tray support?**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please use following JVM argument (this is typed right after `java` command):

```
-Djava.awt.headless=false
```

and tell me the results?